# Google Classroom API Error Code 403 The caller does not have permission PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-workspace, google-classroom, google-api-explorer

I followed the qucikstart tutorial on https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses for creating a course. However, I got the Error 404 PERMISSION_DENIED. I also tried the request on the API Explorer and got the same error. Can someone please advice me on how to create the credentials sufficient for creating a Classroom Course. Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user you are using is using the correct scope for Creating Course. I guess the user should specify the scope - *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses (Manage your Google Classroom classes)*. Also there is a API which you can invoke for a user to know if he has permission to create course. Check this documentation-

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles#permission

[image]